# SSL Cert Validate - Chrome Claims Validity Too Long

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

I have a newly issued SSL cert (expires in 1181 days) which is under the 39 month limit.

Every browser but Chrome accepts the new cert just fine.  Chrome throws a NET::ERR_CERT_TOO_LONG

I've used multiple tools to test the validity of the cert:

[SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=frcdev.fairfaxradiology.com&hideResults=on)

[SSL Tools](http://ssltools.com/?url=frcdev.fairfaxradiology.com)

[SSH Shopper Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=frcdev.fairfaxradiology.com)

[Wormly](https://www.wormly.com/test_ssl/h/frcdev.fairfaxradiology.com/i/52.91.249.252/p/443)

If I check the enddate of the cert with openssl I receive the following:

```
$ openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in ssl.crt
notAfter=May 30 23:59:59 2020 GMT
```

Which is well within 39 months.

The server is running Apache 2.4.25.

I can't seem to figured out why only Chrome is claiming 1181 days is longer than 39 months?

Comment: 1181 days is 39.3 months if you consider 1 month to be 30 days. That's more than 39 months. Chrome rounds months up: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/cert/cert_verify_proc.cc#813

Comment: @jordanm i think the calculation is done more sophisticatedly than that and should account for the actual length of months. result should be 38.82735 months.  Otherwise all the SSL checkers would fail the "Expires" check.

Comment: @jordanm you might be onto something here. If I check the cert the "Not Valid Before" date is actually a few days before the cert was issue...I may have to go back to the cert provider.  Thanks!